RAID0 getting different results between 20.04 and 24.04
I have software RAID0 of 3 NVMe drives, formatted as XFS.
On clean Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS Live Server install, running sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/md0
results in:
/dev/md0:
Timing cached reads:   61944 MB in  1.99 seconds = 31175.26 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 12470 MB in  3.00 seconds = 4155.83 MB/sec

On clean Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS Live Server install, running sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/md0 results in:
/dev/md0:
Timing cached reads:   64208 MB in  2.00 seconds = 32169.80 MB/sec
HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Timing buffered disk reads: 24790 MB in  3.00 seconds = 8262.61 MB/sec

No other configuration was done, just fresh install and running hdparm.

Why are buffered results so different?
What does HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device mean in 20.04.6?

